# Is there a better way i can handle my Generic BaseClass in inheriting classes?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have problems with the usage and understanding of Generics. I've worked with generics before, but now I get to a point where I can't get any further

Here is my basic class which should be extended by other classes:

```
public class BaseFiller<T> {

private WorkBook workBook;
private List<T> act_Bwa;
private List<T> act_Balance;
private List<T> p_l_v_e_L;


public BaseFiller(WorkBook workBook,
                  List<T> act_Bwa,
                  List<T> act_Balance,
                  List<T> p_l_v_e_L) {
    this.workBook = workBook;
    this.act_Bwa = act_Bwa;
    this.act_Balance = act_Balance;
    this.p_l_v_e_L = p_l_v_e_L;
}


protected static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByProperty(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}



protected static <T> Map<Integer, String> mapListToMap(Collection<? extends T> entityList, Function<? super T, Integer> intProperty,
                                                           Function<? super T, String> stringProperty) {
    return entityList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(intProperty, stringProperty));
}


 //Getter & Setter

 }
```

The following class extends the base class:

```
public class FinanceBalanceFiller<T> extends BaseFiller<T> {

.
.
.


public FinanceBalanceFiller(WorkBook workBook, List<T> act_Bwa,
                            List<T> act_Balance,
                            List<T> p_l_v_e_L) {
    super(workBook, act_Bwa, act_Balance, p_l_v_e_L);
}



public Map<Integer, String> makeMapFromAllLists() {
    List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> list : getAct_Bwa()) {
        res.addAll(list);
    }

    //removes all duplicates from List by DbNr
    List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> resWithoutDuplicates = res.stream()
            .filter(distinctByProperty(ResultlinevaluesEntity::getDb_nr))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //creates HashMap (Key = DbNr, Value = name)
    return mapListToHashMap(resWithoutDuplicates, ResultlinevaluesEntity::getDb_nr,
            ResultlinevaluesEntity::getName);
}
```

In the method makeMapFromAllLists() I have problems in my For loop. It spits out a bug that the types are not compatible with each other.

> Error:(116, 68) java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to
>   java.util.List

I understand that, and I changed it that way:

```
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<T> list : getAct_Bwa()) {
        res.addAll(list);
    }
```

But that doesn't work either, because the types don't fit here either. Furthermore I get problems with the Methdode distinctByProperty from the base class. Here the compiler says:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

In the meantime I am totally confused and I can't get any further.

So, my goal is that all the methods in the method makeMapFromAllLists() will not only serve the ListType "ResultLineValuesEntity" but also other types.

Can somebody help me and show me how to deal with generics at this point?

Comment: Are you sure you want to inherit like this `FinanceBalanceFiller<T> extends BaseFiller<T>` and not like this `FinanceBalanceFiller extends BaseFiller<ResultlinevaluesEntity>`?

Comment: The Problem in my case is, that i have at least two differrent types in this class

Comment: The point is, in your line `for (List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> list : getAct_Bwa()) {`, you are assuming `T` is `List<ResultlinevaluesEntity>`, but that assumption is not guaranteed anywhere else.

Comment: yeah right, I don't want it to matter what type the list has... have also specified my goal in question little more

Answer (score 1):

It is the usage of `addAll` instead of `add`, but simplifications exist:

```
List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> res = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> actBwa : getAct_Bwa()) {
    res.add(actBwa);
}

List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> res = new ArrayList<>();
res.addAll(getAct_Bwa());

List<ResultlinevaluesEntity> res = new ArrayList<>(getAct_Bwa());
```

---

***After edited question:*** (not wanting the type parameter T)

There is a (sometimes unavoidable) (anti-)pattern of parallel class hierarchies

If you have an item / entity base class ItemBase.

```
class ItemBase
class ItemA extends ItemBase
class ItemB extends ItemBase
```

And a container base class ContainerBase

```
class ContainerBase<T extends ItemBase>
    List<T> items
    List<T> getItems();

class ContainerA extends ContainerBase<ItemA>
class ContainerB extends ContainerBase<ItemB>
```

This is a good way to have type-safe classes with a distinction between `List<ItemA>` and `List<ItemB>`. Otherwise you could have just `List<ItemBase>`.

Best would be *not* to need `ContainerA` and `ContainerB`.

You could also do (if you do not want a parameter):

```
class ContainerBase
    List<ItemBase> items;
    public List<ItemBase> getItems();

class ContainerA extends ContainerBase
    @Override
    public List<ItemA> getItems() {
        return items.stream().map(ItemA.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

class ContainerB extends ContainerBase
    @Override
    public List<ItemB> getItems() {
        return items.stream().map(ItemB.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah simplifications exists. But i think i was not clear in the first version of my Question. So  I want this type to play no part in this. It should not matter what type the list has. also edit my question

Comment: Ok, nice explanation. Gives me a good new perspective. Thanks :)